# what exactly covers 'the ornamental design of nesting cups'?

Tags: usd686037

Is infringing of this design the exact copy of the design? Can a part of the design CHOICE be copied, for instance the way that the handles stack/nest? If the shape of the handles would be different, but they do nest the same as these ones, is that infringing of the patent?

Answer (score 1):

Determining the scope of a design patent is difficult. How close something needs to be in order to infringe a design patent depends on what came *before* the patent. If the patented design is very different from what came before it, it is interpreted more broadly than it would be if it was a small change from what came before. If all drinking glasses were cylindrical and you came up with the first square glass you might have coverage for a relatively wide range of square shaped glasses.